# ASSIMP Convert .blend to .x with skeleton (armature) and Irrlicht

Tags: export, blender, assimp, 3d-modelling, irrlicht

I'm using Assimp to convert .blend files to .x. The mesh converted well, but when I access the joints I get the scene elements like camera, root, armature. There is some way to export only the mesh and bones?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported. If you are interested in this it would be great to get a feature request for that.